# Record mouse movement at screen edge with QMouseEvent

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

We would like to use mouse movement events (after click) to zoom/pan an image within a `QWidget`. So far this is working great with the following exception: when the cursor reaches the edge of the screen, the `QMouseEvent` position no longer changes and it appears to the `QWidget` that the mouse is not moving.

Is there an elegant way to extract the raw mouse movement data from the `QMouseEvent` in this screen edge condition? Or is it possible to 'freeze' the cursor position on a mouse button press, and then record the mouse movement without moving the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly freeze the cursor. This example freezes you for 10s:

```
p = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
t0 = time.time()
while time.time()-t0 < 10:
    QtGui.QCursor.setPos(p)
```

In the case given, you could move the mouse to the starting position every time there is a move event, so long as the mouse button is down.